# Struggling to identify where the logic error in my lexicographical sorting algorithm lies

Tags: java, string, algorithm, sorting, if-statement

I'm attempting to write a method of a program that manipulates stock transactions. I need to sort my output so that companies are sorted alphabetically, and companies of the same name's asset types (bonds and stocks) are sorted by bonds coming stocks. For example, if I had a Microsoft Bond, Apple Stock, and Microsoft Stock, the output should look like:

Apple Stock, Microsoft Bond, Microsoft Stock

When I run my code, I get this instead:

Apple Stock, Microsoft Stock, Microsoft Bond

I have tried switching around the comparison symbols in case I am doing it backwards, but that only moves it further away from being correct.

```
public int compareTo(Transaction t) {
    if (this.name.compareTo(t.name) == 0) 
    {
      if((this.assetType).compareTo(t.assetType) < 0)
        return -1;
      else if((this.assetType).compareTo(t.assetType) > 0)
        return 1;
      else
        return 0;
    }
    else if((this.name).compareTo(t.name) < 0) {
      return 1;
    }
    else {
      return -1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about `assetType`?

Comment: assetType is a String that holds either "Bond" or "Stock"

Answer (score 1):

The ordering of your fields is reversed, i.e. if `(this.assetType).compareTo(t.assetType) < 0` => `return -1;` and at the same time `if((this.name).compareTo(t.name) < 0)` => `return 1;`. You would have to reverse one of them, for example:

```
public int compareTo(Transaction t) {
    if (this.name.compareTo(t.name) == 0) 
    {
      if((this.assetType).compareTo(t.assetType) < 0)
        return -1;
      else if((this.assetType).compareTo(t.assetType) > 0)
        return 1;
      else
        return 0;
    }
    else if((this.name).compareTo(t.name) < 0) {
      return -1;
    }
    else {
      return 1;
    }
  }
}
```

P.S.: There is also no validation, that could be useful - checking for `null` values, types and so on.